# Are admins able to restrict usage of %AppData%?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, roaming-profile

Currently i have a VSTO Outlook addin that is using the default settings provider to manage configurations. All User configs are marked at Local scope and are thus saved under %LocalAppData%.
I have a reason to change them to be Roaming (%AppData%) scope and it seems to work on my computer (local profile), but there is some uncertainty that it might not be that way for everyone.

So my concern is, is there any scenario in AD/GP environments or otherwise, if i did swap over from Local to Roaming where the addin would cease to work due to the Roaming folder being inaccessible or something like that?

Been trying to figure out any scenarios like this but really the only things i can find is that:

- administrators may turn off roaming profiles, which would just make the roaming folder act like the local folder? (addin still works locally),
- admins may limit the size of the profile which breaks syncing. (addin still works locally)
- admins may exclude my folder from syncing (addin still works locally)

Basically worst case scenario i've been able to come up with is that configs will be local to the device, which is exactly how it works now, no problem.
For those that do use roaming profiles, if i cause them exceed their quota would that possibly break the whole profile?

What else could possibly go wrong? Which pitfalls am i missing (and what are the best practices to overcome them (c# bonus))?

Answer (score 1):

The definition for the **Roaming** folder purpose according to Microsoft is

> Windows uses the **Roaming** folder for application specific data, such as
>   custom dictionaries, which are **machine independent** and **should** roam
>   with the user profile.

According to this, you may and should use the roaming folder for application data. That data may be roaming with the user profile, but it won't be removed (and definitely won't lose accessibility) at any time. (unless the user erased it or limited it)

[more detailed source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/what-is-appdataroaming-and-how-did-it-get-into-my/9987511f-b15b-4f97-bcac-b98960423ce3)

You may notice in the source link that the Roaming folder is in comparison with "Documents And Settings" of good old Windows XP. definitely a place to store application data with safety...